# JavasScript: how do I prevent a user from selecting anything in a select option list without using disable/pointer-events?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to prevent the user from selecting any other value other than the selected value.  Because my company is old and retarded they use IE9 and I am using MVC3/c#.  So I want the View to send back the *pre selected* value to the Controller and prevent the user from changing the value.  I have tried "/pointer_events_polyfill.js", but it doesn't work for getting IE9 to use "pointer-events".

```
<select id="abc">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Is there a javascript function or class that I could use to prevent the user from changing the pre selected value?

Comment: set the `disabled`-attribute for the other options

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be presented to the user as a Select List? Why not just show them the text that you already chose for them?

Comment: I need to be able to set this dynamically - depending on the user's group, they should not be able to change the pre-selected value.

Comment: @user2089039: Dynamically, meaning that you're using javascript to choose it? Can your javascript not change a `span`'s text just as easily as a `select`'s value?

Comment: dynamically from the server --- I basically just need to ensure that the value selected is the pre-selected value either by: preventing the user from changing it or some onclick() function or something

Comment: Did you already try unbind() ? (unbinding the click-event for the options that shouldn't be clickable)

Comment: On clientside you can't prevent anything, you must validate the data on serverside

Comment: Can you show me an example using unbind()?

Comment: @matthias_h: unbind will only remove handlers added by javascript. It won't affect the natural behavior of the browser. Also, click events wouldn't be sufficient, since people can use keyboards and such to make selections.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thx for the info, wasn't sure about that and just guessed, should have looked it up before commenting, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about this. From a usability standpoint, it's probably best just to show users the preselected value, rather than trying to represent it as an input. Inputs tell users that they're allowed to choose, whereas you're basically saying you've already chosen for them. Other options include:

- removing all the `option`s except the one you want from the `select`.

  ```
  $('#abc option[value="saab"]').siblings().remove();
  ```
- disabling the `select`.
- responding to the `change` event, and setting the `select`'s value back to its dynamically-calculated value every time the user changes it.

  ```
  $('#abc').change(function() {$(this).val('saab');});
  ```

Regardless of how you decide to represent this to the user, though, **you mustn't rely on client-side code to enforce their choice**. When the form is submitted, your server will need to calculate the desired value based on the other choices the user has made. Otherwise, *savvy users will be able to hack the value that gets submitted*.

Comment: can you show me an example where you remove all other options that aren't selected?  That is, pre selected.  So in the example above, how would I remove all other options besides "Saab" (since sabb is "selected") thanks

Comment: @user2089039: Sure, I added a couple of code snippets, which you can see examples of at http://jsfiddle.net/jt8vu5rz/ and http://jsfiddle.net/xtnbcqbu/

Comment: $('#abc').change(function() {$(this).val('saab');});  --- this is perfect! but is there a way I can dynamically identify 'saab' instead of using the literal?

Comment: @user2089039: Sure, you can use a variable, or call a function. Presumably you've got some code that's setting this value in the first place, right? So you can put this code there and use the same value. But let me reiterate--this is not an ideal solution. It's a horrible user experience to see a dropdown, and then have the options you select not actually get selected.

Comment: Perhaps: is there a way to loop through each option and remove those option items where not "selected"?

Comment: Yes, but the selected value is set using MVC3 HTML Helpers, so I'm looking for an option where I can getElementById and then perform some type of function.

Comment: `$("#abc option").not(":selected").remove();` ?

Comment: or `var selected = $("#abc option:selected").val();
$('#abc').change(function() {$(this).val(selected);});`

Comment: $('#xxx').change(function() {$(this).val(lastSel_xxx);}); var lastSel_xxx = $("#xxx option:selected").val();  <----- I was able to figure it out based on your response - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the `disabled` attribute to your select:

```
 <select id="abc" disabled>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

see: http://jsbin.com/vozeyajiseco/1/edit

Comment: I can't use "disabled" - mainly because MVC3 sends back null values.  I just need some javascript magic that'll prevent a user from changing the selected value.

Comment: @user2089039: It should not matter if no value is sent to the server. As I mention in my answer, your server needs to calculate this value for itself--showing it dynamically as the user makes their choice is a nice extra, but you cannot rely on javascript tricks to keep them from choosing the wrong value.

Comment: @user2089039 if you're searching for a javascript hack then here's one: `document.getElementById("abc").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: or disable all the options: `$("#abc").children().prop("disabled", true);`